# I cannot assign new value to a nullable variable

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

My intention is to avoid calling the `locateUserPosition()` function if a variable `lat` already has a value. Since I stored the value in shared preferences, I am using the timer to give it enough time to retrieve it.

My problem is when it comes to assigning the values retrieved from shared preferences to userCurrentPosition. After running these two lines, `userCurrentPosition?.latitude = lat!;` and `userCurrentPosition?.longitude = lng!;` userCurrentPosition still managed to be null. Hence this error `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)` when trying to print the value.

Where am I doing it wrong? Why can't I successfully do something as simple as assigning a value to a variable?

```
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataFuture = getData();

    if (lat == null) {
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        if (lat == null) {
          print('location is null');
          locateUserPosition();
        } else {
          userCurrentPosition?.latitude = lat!;
          userCurrentPosition?.longitude = lng!; 

          // After running the two above lines, where lat and lng both have values,
          // they still couldn't be assigned to the userCurrentPosition.latitude and 
          // userCurrentPosition.longitude. The next line shows this error
          // _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

          print('usercurrentposition: ${userCurrentPosition!.latitude}'); // <- error here
        }
      });

      // EasyLoading.showSuccess('Use in initState');
      // debugPrint("radius: $radius");
    } else {
      userCurrentPosition?.latitude = lat!;
      userCurrentPosition?.longitude = lng!;
      // EasyLoading.showSuccess('Use in initState');
      // debugPrint("radius: $radius");
    }
    // setState(() {});
  }
```

EDIT:

Here are screenshots at run time
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DWIz.jpg
The above image link shows that the lat and lng all have values before execution reaches the line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KTru.jpg
The above image link shows that after running the assignment lines, the `userCurrentPosition.lat` and `userCurrentPosition.lng` still manage to remain null. So the assignment in the previous lines did not happen. So it throws the `_CastError` when I try printing the value.

Comment: `userCurrentPosition?.latitude = lat` means, "if `userCurrentPosition` is NOT null, then assign its latitude property; if it is null, ignore this line of code".

Comment: @WSBT Yes, it is null before the assignment statement. Debugging it says it is null but it still does not assign its latitude property. Is there a way that I can better write this statement?

Comment: @jamesdlin While debugging, it clearly shows the values of `lat` and `lng` so they definitely are not null by the time the lines are executing.

Comment: Sorry, I misread.  Your `print` statement throws an error because it uses `userCurrentPosition!` when `userCurrentPosition` is `null`, and the fact that it's `null` means that the earlier assignment attempts to its members won't happen.  What do you expect?  You need to assign an object to `userCurrentPosition` before you can set its members.  Whatever that object is supposed to be won't be magically constructed for you.

Comment: @jamesdlin This is an interesting concept I have never known before. I'll try digging into it and please if you have some resources that can help me learn this, I'll be grateful.